Keyword search with option to remove values
I am trying to help the result of my company search using a remove method. I have this list of values I would like to remove Ltd;inc;inc.;, from the string. I then build a new keyword that would be use to search for the company. One problem is I wanted to remove , but its keeping it , any help would be great.
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string Company = "Foundation Medicine, Inc.";
        string CompanyRemoveValues = "Ltd;inc;inc.;,";
        var RemoveValues = CompanyRemoveValues.ToLower().Split(';').ToList();
        
        string[] companyParts = Company.ToLower().Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        
        StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (string part in companyParts)
                {
                    if (!RemoveValues.Contains(part))
                    {
                        Sb.Append(part);
                        Sb.Append(" ");
                    }
                }

        string Search = Sb.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Keyword");
        Console.WriteLine(Search);
    }
}

Working sample
https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpALaV

Your companyParts contains three elements:foundation,medicine, and inc.. How do you want to handle the medicine, value?

I would want to remove the medicine, to be medicine

Your code could be much better. But if you want to be faithful to your handwriting, adding these few pieces of code will fix it.
string Company = "Foundation Medicine, Inc.";
string CompanyRemoveValues = "Ltd;inc;inc.;,";
var RemoveValues = CompanyRemoveValues.ToLower().Split(';')
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length); // new code

string[] companyParts = Company.ToLower().Split(new Char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string part in companyParts)
{
    // new code 
    var newPart = part;
    foreach (var removeValue in RemoveValues)
    {
        newPart = newPart.Replace(removeValue, "");
    }
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPart))  // new code
    {
        Sb.Append(newPart);
        Sb.Append(" ");
    }
}

string Search = Sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("Keyword");
Console.WriteLine(Search);


This isn't going to filter the comma:
if (!RemoveValues.Contains(part))

Because the comma isn't by itself.  When the string was split on the space character, one of the resulting strings is this:
"Medicine,"

That string is not contained in RemoveValues, so it's not filtered out.
For at least this input data, one way to address it would be to also split on the comma character:
string[] companyParts = Company.ToLower().Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                                                       // here ----^


Alternatively, you could also loop through the RemoveValues to remove them from strings before adding those strings.  For example:
foreach (string part in companyParts)
{
    if (!RemoveValues.Contains(part))
    {
        // maybe like this:
        var result = part;
        foreach (var rem in RemoveValues)
            result = result.Replace(rem, string.Empty);

        Sb.Append(result);
        Sb.Append(" ");
    }
}


You can use Replace function to omit them but also you need to consider all use cases:
for(int i=0; i < companyParts.Count(); i++)
{
   var part = companyParts[i];
   foreach(var removeValue in RemoveValues.Where(x=> part.Contains(x))
     {
        part = part.Replace(removeValue, "");
      }
Sb.Append(part);
Sb.Append(" ");
}

By this way if a word contains multiple removeValue you can replace all of them.
Fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eo0Jss

This does not even compile. You can't assign value to the foreach iteration variable.

@PeterCsala sorry fixed, I'm using mobile and couldn't format the code.
